# Is there a way to do an LDAP query to get records where a particular attribute is the same?

Tags: ldap

I am trying to find an example LDAP query where I can find records where a particular attribute matches one or more other records.  For instance, a user object where the userid is different, but the employee ids are the same.  Is this even possible?

Comment: Where the userid is different than what?

Comment: I have two users, with different user ids but the same employee id.  I am pretty sure the answer is that you can't do this, because basically what I am asking for is a join, but I thought I'd ask before I tried to brute-force this.

Comment: I'm not aware of anyway to do that with LDAP. I'd probably just export from AD and query with SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a single LDAP query no. Unless you know the emplyeeID value you are looking for.

We created an LDAP tool, [Duplicate Attribute Value Locater Tool](http://ldapwiki.willeke.com/wiki/DuplicateAttributeValueLocaterTool), that will do this.

-jim

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to do sub queries within the filter itself. In this case, as long as I understand correctly, you'd like to find users that match :

- `objectClass` of `User`
- match on the value of `employeeID`
- Out of the above subset, find all with a `DISTINCT` 'userid'

If you knew what `userid` to look for, or **NOT** look for, you could expand the inital `AND` clause to include finding, or not finding, that attribute :

`userid` not equal to 12345 :

`(&(objectClass=person)(employeeID=JSmith)(!(userid=12345)))`

`userid` equal to 12345 :

`(&(objectClass=person)(employeeID=JSmith)(userid=12345)`

Answer (score 1):

I found this example for 'myattribute'. Needs some polish, and depending on the size of your directory, it could take a while to run. If that's the case, I'd break it up by attribute sections {attr=aa*, attr=ab*, attr=ac*, etc.}.

```
ldapsearch -x -h ldapserver.domain.com -b ou=myldap,o=mydomain.com "(&(myattribute=aa*))" myattribute | grep '^myattribute:' | sort | uniq -c| sort -n|awk '$1 > 1 { print }'
```

Comment: I know this is not what the OP asked but this is pretty helpful under Linux as you can certainly get the duplicates